# How can I programmatically add a QGraphicsView inside a QMainWindow?

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to add a QGraphicsView(a sub class of it called Menu) inside a QMainWindow programmatically (using code).

In fact I already do that but the problem is the embedded QGraphicsView is not showed.

Here is the code I used inside QMainWindow::init()

```
menuView=new Menu(this);
menuView->show();
```

I already create the scene and insert items inside the Menu class.

What's wrong?

Comment: Is this code snippet all you are doing to create and show your QGraphicsView, or are you using layouts that you are not showing here ?

Comment: In fact this is alla I do in the init() function, but in the QMainWindow there is some frames.
I already tried to add the QGraphicsView to a frame but it doesn't work .

Comment: Why do you need an `init()` function? There's stuff like constructors for that IMHO...

Comment: Yeah this is just to organize my code the init() function is called from within the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
menuView=new Menu(this);
menuView->show();

QLayout* layout=new QVBoxLayout();
layout->addWidget(menuView);
this->setLayout(layout);
```

if you are not using layouts, or

```
menuView=new Menu(this);
menuView->show();

QLayout* layout=this->layout();
layout->addWidget(menuView);
this->setLayout(layout);
```

if your form already have a layout.

Comment: thanks for your help.
I tested this solution but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

When using QMainWindow, use setCentralWidget:

```
int main( int argc, char** argv ) {
    QApplication app( argc, argv );
    ...
    QMainWindow mw;
    Menu menu;
    mw.setCentralWidget( &menu );
    mw.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help.
I tested this solution, it works but the Menu interface take the whole place of the main window, I want just to add Menu in the side of the QMainWindow.

Comment: What do you mean by "in the side"? Try to add another widget as top level widget, set a layout (e.g. QHBoxLayout), and add your Menu to the layout. Whatever widget should go next to the Menu also add to the layout.

Comment: What I want to do is to have a Menu in the left side of the QMainWindow and other frames and components in the other side.

Comment: Then you can either use QHBoxLayout as I described above. Or a QSplitter if you want to have it resizable by the user.